# ASA 5510 Secondary Public IP Range on outside interface

Tags: cisco, nat, cisco-asa

We are in process of upgrading from an ASA5505 to an ASA5510.  I have a co-location configured for 3 ranges of public IP addresses on two different subnets. The 5505 is working as expected.

Example (modified IPs): 174.136.1.1, 72.249.1.1, 72.249.2.1

The firewall is assigned to 174.136.1.2.  When bringing the 5510 online, traffic does not route correctly when NAT rules are created for any IP addresses in this range: 72.249.1.1, 72.249.2.1

- I confirmed the data packets route correctly when assigning a server to an IP that is on the same subnet as the firewall.
- When configuring additional VLANs for IP ranges 72.249.1.1 and 72.249.2.1, all packets route correctly.  I put a switch between the Firewall and Datacenter router. However we do not have enough IPs to assign to additional VLANS.
- I tried to create a static route to 72.249.1.1, 72.249.2.1, that didn't work.
- Packet trace results were a positive but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.
- I do see a Dynamic NAT rule on the 5505 vs Dynamic PAT rule on the 5510. I am unclear what the difference is. I think I have tried to toggle that on the 5510 with no luck.
- I am researching subinterfaces on the 5510 but I'm not sure if that is the solution.

We have a small window to do the firewall upgrade and that is typically late night. I've tried multiple times with no luck. I can't create a test bed environment at the office. I may request another drop from the datacenter for testing purposes. Any help would be appreciated. I can post the full config.

Comment: Have you tried with static nat and correcct access lists (assuming the routing by your ISP is ok for two different blocks)? Also can you see if this is configured: `arp permit-nonconnected`?

Comment: Yes all the NATs are static. I have about 10 servers. All severs with a static NAT using the IP address that is on the same subnet as the firewall works fine. I have this in the config.

"no arp permit-nonconnected"

Comment: You will need this option enabled I guess. Try it like this: `arp permit-nonconnected` and check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need [arp permit-nonconnected](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa-command-reference/A-H/cmdref1/a3.html#pgfId-1837762) enabled for the NAT to work properly.

> arp permit-nonconnected
>
> To enable the ARP cache to also include non-directly-connected
>   subnets, use the arp permit-nonconnected command in global
>   configuration mode. To disable non-connected subnets, use the no form
>   of this command.
>
> Usage Guidelines
>
> The ASA ARP cache only contains entries from directly-connected
>   subnets by default. When the no arp permit-nonconnected command is
>   there (default behavior), the ASA rejects both incoming ARP requests
>   and ARP responses in case the ARP packet received is in a different
>   subnet than the connected interface.
>
> Note that the first case (default behavior) causes a failure in case
>   PAT is configured on the ASA and the virtual IP address (mapped) for
>   PAT is in a different subnet than the connected interface.
>
> Also, we do not recommend enabling this feature unless you know the
>   security risks. This feature could facilitate denial of service (DoS)
>   attacks against the ASA; a user on any interface could send out many
>   ARP replies and overload the ASA ARP table with false entries.
>
> You may want to use this feature if you use:
>
> - Secondary subnets.
> - Proxy ARP on adjacent routes for traffic forwarding.
>
> Examples
>
> The following example enables non-connected subnets:
>
> `ciscoasa(config)# arp permit non-connected`

Comment: I will test this out tonight. I have the datacenter configuring a new drop for me. I will let you know how that goes. It does appear to the issue.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for your input. You have ended countless hours of research.

Comment: @manit, glad that it worked!